# Are stationary states of infinite irreducible Markov chains unique?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose I have a continuous-time Markov chain with a countable state space, and suppose that it is irreducible, in the sense that every state is accessible from every other state.

Since the state space is infinite it need not have a stationary state, but if it does have one, is it guaranteed to be unique? If so, how can I prove this?

In the case of a finite state space the existence and uniqueness of the stationary state follow straightforwardly from the Perron-Frobenius theorem, but the countably infinite case seems not so obvious.

Comment: This should be near immediate viewing this as a renewal reward process in a delayed renewal process— if the steady states are different do the computation with each to get a contradiction (since starting position won’t matter for irreducible positive recurrent chain... you may need mild assumption to rule out pathology for continuous time, e.g. Feller process)

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:** Yes, if a stationary state exists, then it is unique.

**Explanation:** There is indeed an infinite dimensional version of Perron Frobenius theory which yields the result you are seeking for.

More precisely, a continuous-time Markov chain on a countable state space can be described by a stochastic $C_0$-semigroup $T$ on the space $\ell^1$. The Markov chain is irreducible if and only if the semigroup $T$ is irreducible in the sense of positive $C_0$-semigroups on Banach lattices. (That latter definition of irreducibility can, for instance, be found in [1, Definition C-III-3.1 on page 306] or in [2, Definition 14.9 on page 222]).

The fact that irreducibility of the semigroup implies that its fixed space is at most one-dimensional is, for instance, proved in [1, Proposition C-III-3.5(c) on page 310] or in [2, Proposition 14.12(c) on page 224].

**Remarks:**

(a) I'm pretty sure that there are also more stochastic approaches to the theory; but personally, I'm more familiar with the operator theoretic approach described above.

(b) Concerning the definition of irreducibility in [1, Definition C-III-3.1 on page 306], one has to be a bit careful. In contrast to what is claimed in this reference, assertion (iii) there is not equivalent to the other assertions in this definition (and thus, (iii) is not equivalent to irreducibility). However, if the space $E$ under consideration has order continuous norm (as is, for instance, the case for $\ell^1$), then (iii) is indeed equivalent to the other assertions in the definition.

**References:**

[1] Arendt, Grabosch, Greiner, Groh, Lotz, Moustakas, Nagel, Neubrander, Schlotterbeck: One-parameter Semigroups of Positive Operators, 1986 ([zbMATH](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0585.47030) and [link to publisher](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0074922); the book is also freely available on the [homepage of Rainer Nagel](https://www.math.uni-tuebingen.de/de/forschung/agfa/members/rana))

[2] Bátkai, Kramar Fijavž, Rhandi: Positive Operator Semigroups - From Finite to Infinite Dimensions, 2007 ([zbMATH](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1420.47001) and [link to publisher](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-42813-0))